# how to implement click action in firebase push notifications both foreground and background in flutter?

Tags: flutter, push-notification, background, firebase-cloud-messaging, foreground

I have a problem that I have not been able to solve yet
It happens that I need to use the click action of the firebase push notifications both in the foreground and in the background

in the foreground I used the **flutter_local_notifications** library and everything worked fine

```
_firebaseMessaging.configure(
    onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        ///HERE SHOW THE NOTIFICATION IN THE NOTIFICATION CENTER WITH flutter_local_notifications
        _showNotification(message);
    },
    onBackgroundMessage: myBackgroundMessageHandler,
    onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        _openScreen(message);
    },
    onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        _openScreen(message);
    },
    );
```

but in the background I couldn't use the "onBackgroundMessage" so searching in forums I found that I needed to register the plugin from kotlin and I did it this way:

*File Application.kt*

```
class Application : FlutterApplication(), PluginRegistrantCallback {

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        FlutterFirebaseMessagingService.setPluginRegistrant(this);
        FlutterMain.startInitialization(this)
    }

    override fun registerWith(registry: PluginRegistry?) {
        if (!registry!!.hasPlugin("io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging")) {
            FirebaseMessagingPlugin.registerWith(registry!!.registrarFor("io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FirebaseMessagingPlugin"));
        }
    }
}
```

*File MainActivity.kt*

```
class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {
}
```

*File AndroidManifest.xml*

```
<application
        android:name=".Name"
        android:label="Negocio TinBin"
        android:icon="@mipmap/launcher_icon">

<activity
            android:name=".MainActivity">

    <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>

</activity>

</application>
```

With this change it works without problems in the background and when you click if the "myBackgroundMessageHandler" function is executed, but it stopped working in the foreground, I check the log and not even go through "onMessage" of the firebase configuration
Anyone have any idea what I could do to make it work both in the foreground and in the background?

https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/2311

https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging#receiving-messages

Comment: After hours looking for a solution, I decided to try to create a new project with the same code, it turns out that now if everything worked correctly, the only thing that occurs to me is that the initial flutter configurations had a problem with the version, and when creating a new project was solved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to specify the `click_action` inside your js script, in which you have written the cloud functions, without specifying it, you would not be able to get `onResume()` and `onLaunch()` callbacks.

```
"data": {"click_action": "FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK",  }
```

Make sure have this line of code in your Manifests.xml file.

```
<intent-filter>
      <action android:name="FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
  </intent-filter>
```

Comment: Please upvote and accept this as the answer if it helped :)